# How do I prove analytically using co- ordinate geometry that the diagonals of a rhombus are perpendicular to each other

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have a rhombus $ABCD$ with sides $AB,BC,CD$ and $DA$ as s units. With the help of concepts of co ordinate geometry I need to prove that the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ are perpendicular to each other. How do I prove this particular property of rhombus?

Comment: can you use vector geometry? there is a simple solution

Comment: Just co-ordinate geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Say $A(0,0)$ and $C(p,q)$, then $B$ and $D$ are the points of intersection of circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2=1$. Then the coordinates of $B$ and $D$ are the solutions of this system of equations. If we substract these two we get $$2px+2qy =0 \Longrightarrow y=-{p\over q}x$$ 
and $B,D$ define this equation (since they are on it). The line $AC$ has equation $y={q\over p}x$ we have:

$$k_{BD}\cdot k_{AC} = -{p\over q}\cdot {q\over p} =-1 \Longrightarrow AC\bot BD$$

Comment: So this method can also be used to show that if two circles intersect, the chord joining the points of intersection is perpendicular to the line joining the centres. Or alternatively, if we know the chord and the line joining the centres  are perpendicular already we have a potential co-ordinate free proof.

Comment: Note that the first two equations here are equations for the vertices $B$ and $D$ in a rhombus of side $1.$ if we have a side of length $s$ (as given in the original question), the $1$ on the right side of each of these two equations should be replaced by $s^2.$